# rspec controller test with devise authentication

Tags: testing, authentication, rspec, controller

I am having problem with rspec testing controller the devise authentication.

I have a following setup

I have included

```
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
```

in my spec_helper.rb

In my merchants_controller_spec.rb

```
describe MerchantsController do
  before :each do
    @user = Factory(:user)
    @merchant = Factory(:merchant, :user_id => @user.id,:is_approved => false, :is_blacklisted => false)
    controller.stub!(:current_user).and_return(@user)
  end
  describe "GET index" do
    it "assigns all merchants as @merchants" do
      merchant = Factory(:merchant,:is_approved => true, :is_blacklisted => false)
      get :index
      assigns(:merchants).should eq([merchant])
    end
  end
end
```

My merchants_controller.rb

```
class MerchantsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def index
    @merchants = Merchant.approved
    debugger
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @merchants }
    end
  end
end
```

I have a scope approved in merchant model

```
scope :approved, where(:is_approved => true, :is_blacklisted => false)
```

Now my problem is even though i stubbed current_user and returned @user as current_user, My merchants_controller index spec is failing. But if i comment out authenticate_user! then the spec passes,

without authenticate_user! the debugger of index action is caught but with authenticate_user! debugger is not caught.

I think there is problem in subbing current_user and i am not able to figure it out.

Help me out..

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have you read through the docs on [github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)?:

> Devise includes some tests helpers for functional specs. To use them, you just need to include `Devise::TestHelpers` in your test class and use the `sign_in` and `sign_out` methods. Such methods have the same signature as in controllers:

```
sign_in :user, @user   # sign_in(scope, resource)
sign_in @user          # sign_in(resource)

sign_out :user         # sign_out(scope)
sign_out @user         # sign_out(resource)
```

Comment: I replaced controller.stub!(:current_user).and_return(@user)
with sign_in @user but still doesn't solve my problem. I think user is still not authenticated as debugger inside index action is still not caught. Any ideas?

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice. I had a nested Factory to create my admin, and I couldn't figure out why the user was being created but not logged in.

Answer (score 9):

Another alternative

```
RSpec.describe YourController, :type => :controller do
  before do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    allow(controller).to receive(:authenticate_user!).and_return(true)
    allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
  end

  # rest of the code
end
```

Comment: This works for me, for ALL my tests. Guides at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Stub-authentication-in-controller-specs and https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-%28and-RSpec%29 works for one example, but not not whole suite.

Comment: Instead of stubbing authenticate_user!, I just used the above answer (`sign_in @user` method) and the second stub of your answer `allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)`